# unexpected behaviour of c compiler when using enumerate as constant

Tags: c, enumeration

In the following c-code, the function `func1` decides which element of enumerate `ENUM1` is given as input. 
In the first call `func1(ENUM_ELEMENT1);` it works as expected but in the second and third calls the results are wrong (it is expected that the function prints `ENUM_ELEMENT2` and `ENUM_ELEMENT3` respectively but in both cases it prints `ENUM_ELEMENT1`)!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  typedef enum
  {
      ENUM_ELEMENT1 = 0x0000001u,
      ENUM_ELEMENT2 = 0x0000002u,
      ENUM_ELEMENT3 = 0x0000004u,
      ENUM_ELEMENT4 = 0x0000008u,
  } ENUM1;

  void func1( uint32_t inp )
  {
      if (0u != inp & ENUM_ELEMENT1)
      {
          printf("ENUM_ELEMENT1\n");
      }
      else if (0u != inp & ENUM_ELEMENT2)
      {
          printf("ENUM_ELEMENT2\n");
      }
      else if (0u != inp & ENUM_ELEMENT3)
      {
          printf("ENUM_ELEMENT3\n");
      }
      else if (0u != inp & ENUM_ELEMENT4)
      {
          printf("ENUM_ELEMENT4\n");
      }
  }

  int main( void )
  {
      func1(ENUM_ELEMENT1);       // prints ENUM_ELEMENT1    --> correct
      func1(ENUM_ELEMENT2);       // prints ENUM_ELEMENT1    --> wrong!
      func1(ENUM_ELEMENT3);       // prints ENUM_ELEMENT1    --> wrong!
      getchar();
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: it works as I explained, in the 2nd and 3rd cases wrong result!

Comment: ...and that is why you should *always* use parenthesis to group your logic expressions. You might not remember operator precedence as well as you might think... and even if you do, it makes things easier for the next guy who might not.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks

Comment: I prefer `if (inp & ENUM_ELEMENT1) { /*...*/ }`, avoiding a redundant implicit comparison with `0` and avoiding possible extra unneeded conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The expression `0u != inp & ENUM_ELEMENT1` is equal to `(0u != inp) & ENUM_ELEMENT1`. If `inp` is non-zero then `0u != inp` will be true, which is convertible to the integer `1`, and `1 & 1` is indeed "true".